# How to use maven to build the project which was clone from github?

Tags: maven, intellij-idea

I'm new to Intellij. I used Intellij to clone a project from github, now I want to know how to use maven to build and run it.

Comment: It doesn't matter if the project is a git clone or an example from a tutorial page, as long it's a maven project.

Answer (score 1):

Verify that the project you cloned from github has a `pom.xml` in the **root** of the project.

From there, you can open up IntelliJ and "open" the `pom.xml` - this will cause it to be imported.

Alternatively, if you already have an intellij project, right click on the `pom.xml` and select the option (from memory) "+ Add Maven Project".

Once the pom.xml is recognised in IntelliJ, you should see the "Maven Projects" panel on the right hand side of the intellij frame.